# table lock status for use in if ... then statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to determine within a MySQL event if a table is locked.

If it is not, then I want to run a query.

I don't know the systems tables well or how to get this into a variable for the comparison in the the If .. Then.

Thanks,

Bud

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? DB engine constantly locks and releases the table for different queries. Even if you obtain the current status of a table by the time you execute you query table might be locked again. DB engines handles locking and queries queue.

Comment: The data will be uploaded into a incoming table twice an day, and then upserted into a prod table.  so the file will be inactive except when it is being created or ingested. the runs will be about 6 hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these [locking functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html#function_is-free-lock). Essentially you can obtain a named lock by using `GET_LOCK()` function like so:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('myNamedLock');
// Do your thing in the app, then
SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('myNamedLock');
```

Your current session will own the lock and no other session will be able to obtain a lock with the same name.
It is a sort of pseudo locking, nothing is actually locked but if you want to make sure another connection is not doing something on the DB, make that other connection obtain the named lock first and then for your current connection keep checking if lock has been released/is available.